# How to add each item array into specific line in python?

Tags: python, list, readline

I have file.txt:

```
textaaa 1
textbbb
textaaa 2
textbbb
textaaa 3
textbbb
```

I want to add values in an array (cc) into a specific line by reading the file first and try to write the line:

```
cc = [10, 9, 8]

with open("file.txt", "r") as in_file:
    buf = in_file.readlines()
    
with open("file.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for line in buf:
        if line == "textbbb\n":
            for item in cc:
                line = line + "textccc %d\r" % (item)
        out_file.write(line)
```

However, what I get is:

```
textaaa 1
textbbb
textccc 10
textccc 9
textccc 8
textaaa 2
textbbb
textccc 10
textccc 9
textccc 8
textaaa 3
textbbb
textccc 10
textccc 9
textccc 8
```

What I want is:

```
textaaa 1
textbbb
textccc 10
textaaa 2
textbbb
textccc 9
textaaa 3
textbbb
textccc 8
```

I think the issue is in the last for loop. Any suggestion to silver this problem?

Comment: Is the number of entries in `cc` the same as the number of `textbbb` entries or do you need to reiterate through `cc`?

Comment: are there always 2 lines (`textaaa N` and `textbbb`) to put `cc` in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to iterate over the whole list each time, but just use the next item each time.  You could use a counter (see other answers).  The alternative shown here is to make an iterator using `iter` and then when you want the next value you call `next` on that iterator:

```
cc = [10, 9, 8]

with open("file.txt", "r") as in_file:
    buf = in_file.readlines()

iterator = iter(cc)
with open("file.txt", "w") as out_file:     
    for line in buf:
        if line == "textbbb\n":
            item = next(iterator)
            line = line + f"textccc {item}\n"
        out_file.write(line)
```

If the length of your `cc` list is less than the number of occurrences of `"textbbb"`, then you will get an exception in one form or another.  (In this case it would be a `StopIteration`, but if you are using a counter and list indexing then it would be an `IndexError`.)

Note also the use of an f-string for output formatting. The use of `%` for string formatting in your code is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subset your list instead of looping over it:
right now you're doing this:

```
for line in buf:             #for each line of text
    if line == "textbbb\n":  # if there's a match...
        for item in cc:      # write a newline for each item in my list..
            [...]
    out_file.write(line)
```

ergo, your list gets entirely written over at each match. A very quick and dirty way to do write a single item is:

```
offset = 0
for line in buf:
    if line == "textbbb\n":
        line = line + "textccc %d\r" % (cc[offset])
        offset+=1
    out_file.write(line)
```

EDIT: also, be wary that this solution will inevitably bug out if the last line of your file matches your "textbbb" pattern, since there will be no endline ('\n') character this time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate all the list each time you find `textbbb`. It is enough to use counter and increment it after each positive check:

```
cc = [10, 9, 8]

with open("file.txt", "r") as in_file:
    buf = in_file.readlines()

with open("file.txt", "w") as out_file:
    i = 0
    for line in buf:
        if line == "textbbb\n":
            line = line + "textccc %d\r" % (cc[i])
            i += 1
        out_file.write(line)
```

#### Output:

```
textaaa 1
textbbb
textccc 10
textaaa 2
textbbb
textccc 9
textaaa 3
textbbb
```

Note that the last line (`textccc 8`) is not added because the last row was `textbbb`, not `textbbb\n`